# Unable to present 2nd UIviewcontroller with UIbutton

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am making a simple app that have 2 buttons that goes to two different viewcontroller. the alert button is working while the watchlist button is not working. Here is my code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let alertButton = UIButton(type: .system)
let watchListButton = UIButton(type: .system)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //alert button
    self.view.addSubview(alertButton)
    alertButton.setTitle("  Alert  ", for: UIControlState.normal) // what is UIControleState.normal?
    alertButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    alertButton.backgroundColor = .green
    alertButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 500)
    alertButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true
    alertButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 220).isActive = true

    alertButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nextPg), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)


    //watch list button
    self.view.addSubview(watchListButton)
    watchListButton.setTitle("  Watchlist  ", for: UIControlState.normal) // what is UIControleState.normal?
    watchListButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    watchListButton.backgroundColor = .green
    watchListButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 200)

    watchListButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true
    watchListButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true

    alertButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(wlPage), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

}
@objc func wlPage() {

    let wlp = watchListController()
    present(wlp, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@objc func nextPg() {

    let wllc = AlertListController()
    present(wllc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

upon running, here is the error I got in xcode

```
Simulator user has requested new graphics quality: 100
Warning: Attempt to present <newApp.watchListController: 0x7f887851f600> on <newApp.ViewController: 0x7f887850a0d0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

May I know what is going on and how can I solve this? Thank you!

Comment: The warning is stating that when you are trying to present the `watchListController` the `ViewController` is not the `rootViewController` for the current window. Are you pressing the button after you present the `alertListController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second button, you called `addTarget` on the first button again.  So when you press your alert button, it tries to present both viewControllers, and the second `present` fails.  The watchList button actually does nothing.

Change this:

```
alertButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(wlPage), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

to:

```
watchListButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(wlPage), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

---

Also, setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on a button means its `frame` will not be used.  You should set constraints for the widths and heights of your buttons instead of setting the `.frame.size`.